# meaning of "to quell the notion"

Tags: meaning, expressions

"To quell the notion" probably means something like "to stop something being an issue", but what is its meaning in terms of emotions - is it offensive, neutral etc.?

Comment: Words are offensive or neutral depending on how they are used. Saying *I want to quell this superstitious notion* is neutral but saying *I want to quell the superstitious notion you believe in* is not.

Comment: @vickyace - Yes, but the word "quell" itself includes force, so maybe there are more gentle synonyms to "to quell the notion".

Comment: Are you asking for alternatives?

Comment: No, I just want to know if this expression has some emotional aspect to it, like "to forcefully end something".

Comment: Of course it does. A notion is fabricated because of feelings and the talks of quelling it, the notion, will have an impact, which is an entirely different discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quell) entry for 'quell'

> quell v [with object]
>
> 1 Put an end to (a rebellion or other disorder), **typically by the
>   use of force.**
>
> *extra police were called to quell the disturbance*
>
> 1.1 Subdue or silence (someone)
>
> *Connor quelled him with a look*
>
> 1.2 Suppress (a feeling)
>
> *she quelled an urge to race up the stairs*

(bolding mine) certainly does nothing to dissipate the notion that 'quell' carries at least a connotation of the use of force (physical or otherwise). 'Connor quelled him with a look' shows some degree of confrontation.

One list of synonyms

> put an end to, stamp out, put a stop to, end, finish, get rid of,
>   crush, put down, check, crack down on, curb, nip in the bud, thwart,
>   frustrate, squash, quash, subdue, suppress, repress, quench,
>   extinguish, stifle, abolish, terminate, beat, overcome, defeat, rout,
>   destroy, demolish, annihilate, wipe out, extirpate

they add (for the main sense) reinforces this notion.

However, one synonym from the other list given by ODO (for their sense 1.2) does not carry this connotation and is also used idiomatically:

**allay the notion**